# The prime numbers that divide $10^4-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to find the prime numbers that divide $10^4-1$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**HINT**

1. $x^2 - y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)$
2. $101$ is prime

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $10^4 - 1 = (100 + 1)(100 - 1) = 3^2 \times 11 \times 101$

Comment: No. $101=99+2$ not divisible by $3$, neither by $5$ or $7$ or $11$, so, it is prime.

Comment: But $3\times 37=111$, not $101$.

Comment: @PerManne Edited :-)

Answer (score 1):

$$10^4-1=(10^2-1)(10^2+1)=(10-1)(10+1)(101)=9\times11\times101$$ which implies that the prime divisors are $3,11$ and $101$.

Answer (score 0):

$$9999:9=1111 \\ 1111:11=101 $$
So, $9999=3^2\cdot 11\cdot 101$.

Comment: I have a question/comment about readability: why use colons rather than slashes?

Comment: @rschwieb, it's the common division notation in some locales...

Comment: @vonbrand I don't have any on hand, but I would venture to guess that far more people would recognize $9999/9=1111$. It's not a big deal since the context is so simple, but I think it's a fact to bear in mind for future posts.